# Java - Android Studio - Shuffle column of 2D array from XML

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

I have an xml that holds an array of arrays

```
<resources>
   <array name="oneAs">
    <item>"1option1"</item>
    <item>"1option2"</item>
    <item>"1option3"</item>
    <item name="answer">"1answer"</item>
</array>
<array name="twoAs">
    <item>"2option1"</item>
    <item>"2option2"</item>
    <item>"2option3"</item>
    <item name="answer">"2answer"</item>
</array>

<!--all answers -->
<array name="allAs">
    <item>@array/oneAs</item>
    <item>@array/twoAs</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

and I've already returned the row position that it needs to be

```
Integer pos = getQs(q);
```

I just need the columns shuffled upon each call... for example if pos is 0
then it would return the items of "oneAs" array shuffed. if pos is 1 then it would return items of "twoAs" array shuffled.
allAs[0][shuffledarray]
allAs[1][shuffledarray]

my xml array of arrays is currently being held here

```
TypedArray answers = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.allAs);
```

but i'm not sure exactly how to get that into a 2dim array.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As a computer programmer, it is important to learn how to break a problem into smaller pieces. **Don't try to do everything all at once.** Instead break this into several steps: 1. Parse the XML into an array. 2. Get a column from the array. 3. Shuffle the column. In a well-designed solution, each of these steps is started by calling a single method.

Comment: I agree, and this question probably was too scattered to pin it down to one thing so I apologize. I'd divided the problem up several different ways and looked for many solutions and put the question up as a frustrating last resort, so again yes I should have broken this up better in the initial question. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Instead of "shuffling" the data, anytime you need to access the data from any of the arrays, you can Randomize the index. You can do something like so:

```
Random rand = new Random ();
rand.nextInt(array.length());
```

Something like this doens't really have a solution.

Option 2: There are also different shuffling algorithms. Depending on what class you are using to create the array, you could use Fisher-Yates shuffle:

```
  // Implementing Fisher–Yates shuffle
  static void shuffleArray(Object[] ar)
  {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
      int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
      // Simple swap
      int a = ar[index];
      ar[index] = ar[i];
      ar[i] = a;
    }
  }
```

I would suggest to do Option 2 as it's easier to read and understand. You can't necessary edit the XML. That goes against what the XML files were meant for for Android.

To get your TypeArray to a 2dim array, see this article:  http://basememara.com/storing-multidimensional-resource-arrays-in-android/. It's exaclt what you are looking for. The solution is built into Android. You kind of have to create your own code to exact the information you need.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I can't just randomize it each time because then it has the opportunity to duplicate, and I just need them to appear once and shuffled. But im not sure exactly how to get my array of arrays from my xml to the a java 2dim array. its being held here

    TypedArray answers = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.allAs);

and i need to get it to a 2dim array first before I shuffle. I appreciate the algorithm!

Comment: I see what you're doing with the randomize index now, sorry yes that would work. but the problem still remains to get that array into a 2dim java array